# Figuring out memory hogging process in a Linux centos machine

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, performance, memory

I have a micro instance of Centos AMI from EC2 to run my dev instances.  Applications keep on blowing off due to memory issues.

How can I find out process that are taking memory and take decisions to terminate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this in all my .bashrc's:
`alias memhogs="ps -A -ao rss,comm | sort -rn | sed -n '1,5{s/^//;s/ /\t/p}'"`
It shows you top 5 memory hogs.  As for decisions... well, that's application specific really so can't help you there.